# ImportError: cannot import name 'URL' from 'sqlalchemy.engine'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Why I cannot make sqlalchemy.engine working correctly?

I have installed SQLAlchemy

```
 pip install SQLAlchemy
```

I have following code in Python

```
 from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
```

It cause error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'URL' from 'sqlalchemy.engine' (C:\Python\Python3.8.9\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to install it with this command:

`pip3 install flask-sqlalchemy`

If it doesnt worked then try above commands with --user at the end of both commands.

`pip3 install flask-sqlalchemy --user`

Comment: I did both installation and still same error occurs.

Comment: It's clearly something missing in your virtualenv (assuming you're in virtualenv). If you have a requirements.txt file do `pip3 -r requirements.txt`

Also, specifying your project structure would help.

Comment: Problem solved by installing in virtual env

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the SQLAlchemy version. Please install the latest version

```
pip3 install snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.4.32
```

and it will work fine.

Comment: It is showing error, "cannot find the version."